# CSS for Fixed Width and Scalable Height

Tags: css

How to make a text box  fill the entire length of the side bar whose length is not fixed? Width= 250px

```
<div id="Text-box"><div/>
```

Please suggest CSS for height.

Answer (score 1):

First approach should be to use

`height: 100%` That will make the element's height take 100% of height of its parent

If you want to take height of the view, you can consider

`height: 100vh`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague and this answer a little bit trivial, but have you tried:

```
height:100%;
```